# Gmaps4rails - how to set clustering grid size

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I have multiple markers close to each other and want to cluster them together up to a specific zoom. I found this: [click](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Markers).

My question is where and how should I pass cluterer_gridSize to set the grid?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues with Gmaps4rails few weeks ago, as you can see the gem as not been updated for a very long time. I stumbled upon this [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/geocoder-display-maps-and-find-places-in-rails/) after a thorough search. It is advisable and more efficient to develop your own module for the integration of GoogleMaps in rails, this tutorial will teach you that. You will be able to customise display of markers and clusters in all ways you want. I was able to follow that tutorial and I got my desired result.